# Neosemantics: Linking ontology and label property graph

Tags: neo4j, rdf

I'm trying to export an existing Label property graph in neo4j as RDF and trying to use neosemantics for that purpose and for the sake of PoC I tried to use the example database with Movie dataset that comes preinstalled with Neo4j desktop.

Below are the steps I followed

1. Create Ontology using cypher [Reference here](https://github.com/jbarrasa/explicitsemanticsneo4j/blob/master/movieontology.cypher)
2. Data already exists in the neo4j desktop
3. Init configuration `CALL n10s.graphconfig.init();`

Pretty much that's it. I'm pretty sure I have missed some steps and reading the docs could give me some hint, but I thought to ask here as well to get a direction so as to speed up a bit.

I can access the Ontology using :GET `http://localhost:7474/rdf/neo4j/onto`

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<neo4j://graph.schema#WROTE> a owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:range <neo4j://graph.schema#Movie>;
  rdfs:domain <neo4j://graph.schema#Person>;
  rdfs:label "WROTE" .

<neo4j://graph.schema#RANGE> a owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:range <neo4j://graph.schema#Class>;
  rdfs:domain <neo4j://graph.schema#ObjectProperty>;
  rdfs:label "RANGE" .

<neo4j://graph.schema#ACTED_IN> a owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:label "ACTED_IN";
  rdfs:domain <neo4j://graph.schema#Person>;
  rdfs:range <neo4j://graph.schema#Movie> .

........
```

I can validate the Label property graph against the Ontology using Cypher like this

```
// DatatypeProperty domain semantics meta-rule
MATCH (n:Class)<-[:DOMAIN]-(p:DatatypeProperty) 
WITH DISTINCT n.uri as classUri, n.label as classLabel, p.uri as prop, p.label as propLabel
MATCH (x) WHERE  x[propLabel] IS NOT NULL AND NOT classLabel IN labels(x)
RETURN  id(x) AS nodeUID, 
        'domain of ' + propLabel + ' [' + prop + ']' AS `check failed`,  
        'Node labels: (' + reduce(s = '', l IN Labels(x) | s + ' ' + l) + ') should include ' + classLabel AS extraInfo
```

But what I cannot do is access the data as RDF, like for example

```
:POST /rdf/neo4j/cypher
{ "cypher" :"match (m: Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor: Person) match (m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(director: Person) where m.title = 'The Matrix' RETURN m, actor, director", "format": "RDF/XML"}
```

returns Empty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

</rdf:RDF>
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: at which point did you load the RDF data? I mean, so far you simply created the ontology schema or not?

Comment: also, don't you have to call the export function? Like explained in the docs how to export RDF data: https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/tutorial/#_exporting_data

Comment: @UninformedUser The data is an existing neo4j graph and not imported from an existing RDF. I only created the Ontology and I was hoping that I can export the data as RDF confirming the defined ontology.

Answer (score 0):

The GraphConfig is only needed when you are going to store RDF data into Neo4j but if you're working with a "native" property graph you don't need it.

You can get rid of it running `call n10s.graphconfig.drop();`

Once you've done that your POST request to the cypher/RDF endpoint should return the expected results serialised as RDF/XML